# Adding a symbol after every word in a text file

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, file

I have two files with 4000+ words in each file. I want to add a symbol after every word in oreder to use them inside a regex pattern. This is what is started with (not alot..):

```
  Dim Positive_Words As String
    Dim Negative_Words As String


    Positive_Words = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\positive.txt")
    Negative_Words = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\negative.txt")

    For Each word As String In Positive_Words

        'What i need to write here in order to add a symbol "|" after every word?

    Next
```

Questions:

- Is there any way to do this in vb or in any other way (Word 2013 or anything else)?
- A regex pattern with 4000+ words is acceptable?

Comment: replacing space with `|` should be acceptable to you then

Comment: thats kinda weird for me to answer, but you can do it in almost any editor.

Comment: see this : http://regex101.com/r/rN2gB8, here I have searched space and replaced with `|`. the result is i think what you want

Comment: thanks lol...didnt know this thing exist :)..do you think 4000 words regex pattern will crush?

Comment: 4000 words is pretty small - in English, about 20KB.  No problem.

Comment: What's `Negative_Words` doing there ?

Comment: i got two files: positive words and negative words..

Comment: Re: "Another Question" - you get one question per... err... question. Please ask a new question for that if your favourite search engine doesn't help you with it.

Comment: If regex will recognize the words to put a symbol in, won't it recognize the words without the symbol by replacing the `|` with a ` ` in your original pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Positive_Words As String
Dim Negative_Words As String


Positive_Words = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\positive.txt").Replace(" ", "|")
Negative_Words = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\negative.txt").Replace(" ", "|")
```

Comment: Since the OP said "add a symbol", the replacement text should be `"| "`, not just `"|"`.  But yeah, dead simple.